# Why would the JVM suddenly not allocate up to the maximum heap setting, even when running low on memory and with plenty of free OS memory?

Tags: memory-management, java-8, jvm

My JVM is set to have a maximum heap size of 2GB. It is currently running slowly due to being low on memory, but it will not allocate beyond 1841MB (even though it has done so before on this run). I have over 16GB memory free.

Why would this suddenly happen to a running JVM? Could it be because it is "fenced in" - it cannot get a larger continuous range of physical memory?

This is for java 1.8.0_73 (64bit) on Windows 10. But I have seen this now and then for other java versions and on Windows 7 and XP too.

Comment: "It is currently running slowly due to being low on memory," - how have you determined that?

Comment: The JVM memory use is very close to the amount of heap allocated (not less than 80%), it is running slowly, but has increased CPU usage. It appears to have stopped paying attention to -Xmx and MinFreeHeapRatio, (doesn't allocate remaining memory up to -Xmx even if it is available on the system) and after a long while it throws an OutOfMemoyError. I have seen this behaviour before, whether it allocated up to -Xmx or not - in this case it didn't and I am curious why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

32 bit JVMs usually struggle to use more than about 1800Mb. Exactly how much they can allocate depends on your Operating System and how it lays out the 32 bit address space (which can vary between runs).

Use a 64 bit JVM to get more.

Comment: It is a 64bit JVM, and it had allocated more memory earlier in the program run. It is just as if it decided to free some of that and go into starvation mode suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

Start JVM with

```
java -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m
```

This will preallocate 2GB at JVM startup (even if not needed).

Comment: Yes, but it won't then release memory back to the OS when it is not needed. I am interested in possible causes in the first instance, once I have an idea about those, then I can think about what is the right thing to do. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? Does it allocates 2GB?

Comment: Yes, and it then releases some of those 2GB back to the OS (as it should). It then _may or may not_ later decide not to allocate the 2GB (or more) again. The question from my point of view is why does the VM sometimes impose a limit on heap memory, which I have not set, to the detriment of performance when there is plenty of memory available.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a program run faster by just increasing the heap memory. A program may be slow due to various reasons. 
In your case, may be it's not because of the memory usage, as the increase in the heap memory does not cause the program to use that memory to the fullest, or run faster. The heap is used up if you create a lot of objects which are in use and not garbage collected.

The other reason for the slowness could be due to some parts of the program using up the processing power (poorly performing algorithms ?).
It could also be due to slow I/O operations (file reads/writes ?).

These are only a few reasons. We can determine the slowness by getting to know more about your program. 
You could look for slow running parts of your code by going through its logs (if any) or by using various profiling tools like jconsole (shipped with jdk), VisualVM, etc.
You could also tune your JVM by passing various parameters to customize the Garbage collection, various parts of the heap, thread stack size, etc.

Comment: Hello, thank you, true in general, but it is very likely to be memory constraints in this particular case. If the JVM is memory constrained, then more memory will result in fewer GC pauses, less GC CPU usage and faster execution. I have seen the symptoms before - slowdown accompanied by high JVM CPU usage (multiple cores for a single thread program) due to GC. In this case the question is why would the JVM not allocate memory up to the -Xmx limit when there is plenty free memory and it is starved for memory.